# Why does featnames(myDFM) contain features of more than one or two tokens?

Tags: r, quanteda

I'm working with a large 1M doc corpus and have applied several transformations when creating a document frequency matrix from it:

```
library(quanteda)
corpus_dfm <- dfm(tokens(corpus1M), # where corpus1M is already a corpus via quanteda::corpus()
                  remove = stopwords("english"),
                  #what = "word", #experimented if adding this made a difference
                  remove_punct = T,
                  remove_numbers = T,
                  remove_symbols = T,
                  ngrams = 1:2,
                  dictionary = lut_dict,
                  stem = TRUE)
```

Then to look at the resulting features:

```
dimnames(corpus_dfm)$features
[1] "abandon"                                      
[2] "abandoned auto"                               
[3] "abandoned vehicl"
...
[8] "accident hit and run"
...
[60] "assault no weapon aggravated injuri"
```

Why are these features more than 1:2 bigrams long? Stemming appears to have been successful, but the tokens appear to be sentences and not words.

I tried adjusting my code to this: `dfm(tokens(corpus1M, what = "word")` but there was no change.

I tried to make a tiny reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse) # just for the pipe here
example_text <- c("the quick brown fox",
                  "I like carrots",
                  "the there that etc cats dogs") %>% corpus
```

Then if I apply the same dfm as above:

```
> dimnames(corpus_dfm)$features
[1] "etc."
```

This was surprising because nearly all word have been removed? Even stopwords unlike before, so I'm more confused!
I'm also now not able to create a reproducible example despite just trying to. Maybe I've misunderstood how this function works?

How can I create a dfm in quanteda where there are only 1:2 word tokens and where stopwords are removed?

Comment: That's not what I get from your example, but I cannot apply the dictionary without knowing what it is. If you supply the dictionary I will complete my answer.

Comment: Hi @KenBenoit I have added the dictionary via dput on the post now

Comment: **quanteda** dictionaries are S4 objects and the `dput` drops some of their attributes, such as the names in the list. Can you save it using `save` or `saveRDS`, and post a link to the file on Dropbox or some other stored location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** Why are the feature (names) in the dfm so long?

Answer: Because the application of the dictionary in the `dfm()` call replaces the matches to your unigrams and bigram features with the dictionary keys, and (many of) the keys in your dictionary consist of multiple words.  Example:

```
lut_dict[70:72]
# Dictionary object with 3 key entries.
# - assault felony:
#     - asf
# - assault misdemeanor:
#     - asm
# - assault no weapon aggravated injury:
#     - anai
```

**Second question**:  In reproducible example, why are almost all words gone?

Answer: Because the only match of a dictionary value to the features in the dfm was to the "etc." category.

```
corpus_dfm2 <- dfm(tokens(example_text), # where corpus1M is already a corpus via quanteda::corpus()
                  remove = stopwords("english"),
                  remove_punct = TRUE,
                  remove_numbers = TRUE,
                  remove_symbols = TRUE,
                  dictionary = lut_dict,
                  ngrams = 1:2,
                  stem = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
corpus_dfm2
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (66.7% sparse).
# 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    etc.
#   text1    0
#   text2    0
#   text3    1

lut_dict["etc."]
# Dictionary object with 1 key entry.
# - etc.:
#     - etc
```

If you do not apply the dictionary, then you see:

```
dfm(tokens(example_text),   # the "tokens" is not necessary here
    remove = stopwords("english"),
    remove_punct = TRUE,
    remove_numbers = TRUE,
    remove_symbols = TRUE,
    ngrams = 1:2,
    stem = TRUE)
# Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 18 features (66.7% sparse).
# 3 x 18 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#        features
# docs    quick brown fox the_quick quick_brown brown_fox like carrot i_like
#   text1     1     1   1         1           1         1    0      0      0
#   text2     0     0   0         0           0         0    1      1      1
#   text3     0     0   0         0           0         0    0      0      0
#        features
# docs    like_carrot etc cat dog the_there there_that that_etc etc_cat cat_dog
#   text1           0   0   0   0         0          0        0       0       0
#   text2           1   0   0   0         0          0        0       0       0
#   text3           0   1   1   1         1          1        1       1       1
```

If you want to keep the features not matched, then replace `dictionary` with `thesaurus`.  Below, you will see that the "etc" token has been replaced with the upper-cased key "ETC.":

```
dfm(tokens(example_text), 
    remove = stopwords("english"),
    remove_punct = TRUE,
    remove_numbers = TRUE,
    remove_symbols = TRUE,
    thesaurus = lut_dict,
    ngrams = 1:2,
    stem = TRUE)
Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 18 features (66.7% sparse).
3 x 18 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
       features
docs    quick brown fox the_quick quick_brown brown_fox like carrot i_like
  text1     1     1   1         1           1         1    0      0      0
  text2     0     0   0         0           0         0    1      1      1
  text3     0     0   0         0           0         0    0      0      0
       features
docs    like_carrot cat dog the_there there_that that_etc etc_cat cat_dog ETC.
  text1           0   0   0         0          0        0       0       0    0
  text2           1   0   0         0          0        0       0       0    0
  text3           0   1   1         1          1        1       1       1    1
```